# Create an Excel Formula that uses filtered data

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm trying to design a second page that shows % results of my data on page 1.
For example, Column F & G allow manual entry of numbers 1-4 which are based off data the user types in at another location.

This is being used for trade tracking in investments so there will be quite a few numbers but the end result will be a row will show a specific stock, it's subsequent data, whether it made or lost money, etc.

What I want to do in page 2 is using the numbers 1-4 which were typed in at columns F & G, translate that into an edge on page 2.

For example, if there were 50 columns of data typed out for trades executed, I could take the number of winning trades of a certain setup (say number 3) and divide that by the total trades of 50 to come out with a win % for that setup.

However, I have no clue to how to translate that forumla into a filter formula so that on page 2 I could see that of the numbers 1-4 (4 different setups) I could easily see the highest and lowest win % to determine the best setup to use.

I'm not the best in excel but I understand enough to code most of that, I simply have no idea how to take that end formula and add a filter to it so that it only uses partial results.  I've got 4 other formulas I want to use on page 2 as well to help build something that could really benefit myself, but if someone could just show me how to filter data into a formula, I think I could take it form there.

Thanks for the help
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this with array formulas

`=MAX(IF(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$50=$A2,$E$2:$E$50))`

(Press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** [CSE], instead of just *Enter* when entering *Array Formulas*)

Also, take a look a the `SUMPRODUCT` function.  It comes in very handy for filtering data. Here are some helpful links...

https://www.get-digital-help.com/2017/12/07/sumproduct-multiple-criteria/

https://www.get-digital-help.com/2017/12/08/sumproduct-and-if-function/

https://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/09/01/extract-a-unique-distinct-list-by-matching-items-that-meet-a-criterion-in-excel/